# Объясните возвращаемый код в ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemClicked, int position,long id) {
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен.

Comment: Здесь не возвращается никакой код и никакая переменная ничего не делает - все они всего лишь хранят значения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В коллбэк:

```
void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

передаются следующие параметры:

- `parent` – родительское представление для `view`;
- `view` – объект класса `View` – элемент списка, по которому было произведено нажатие;
- `position` – позиция `view` в адаптере;
- `id` – id элемента.

**UPD**: [@pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff):

> Стоит добавить, что для структур данных, не имеющих `ID` (например массив или коллекция) значение аргумента `id = position`.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что для структур данных, не имеющих ID (например массив или коллекция) значение аргумента id = position.

Comment: @pavlofff, Не очень понял. Здесь обрабатывается нажатие по `View`, каким образом с этим связаны массивы и коллекции?

Comment: В адаптере связывается `View` и данные, логично при клике на айтем получить ссылку на данные, которые он отображает (позицию в массиве или коллекции или ID в БД). Например для `SimpleCursorAdapter` четвертый аргумент вернет ID записи в курсоре, по которой заполнялся `View`, для ArrayAdapter будет так же возвращена позиция в списке, как и в третьем аргументе.

Comment: Этот id это не id вью по которой кликали, а id в БД, к примеру. Вас должно было насторожить уже то, что ID `View` имеют тип `int`, а не `long`

Comment: @pavlofff, Кстати да, `long` я заметил, но не придал должного значения. Спасибо, не знал этого. Обновил пост.